# How can I get gradle to install an IntelliJ plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I would like to make a gradle task that automatically installs the [lombok plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok-plugin). Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, the Intellij plugin and Gradle task are two independent separate processes.

However, based on my installation of lombok plugin into Intellij, I think you just need to have the jars copied over to the [plugin support directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-intellij-idea-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html), and restart the Intellij, it would show the plugin as installed.

```
$ ls -lart  ~/Library/Application\ Support/IntelliJIdea2017.2/lombok-plugin/lib/
intellij-patcher-agent-0.15.17.2.jar  lombok-plugin-0.15.17.2.jar
```

You can do that copy over either manually or by Gradle task. But I'd rather do the installation thru Intellij.